# Writing and expression to find the probability

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

Suppose (x) and (y) are independent lives. $T(x)$ and $T(y)$ denotes the future lifetimes. How do I write an expression to find out the probability  that exactly one of the dies within the next 10 years? the formula i thought of is $Pr[T(x)<10$ or $T(y)<10]$-$Pr[T(x)$ and $T(y)<10]$ but I am not sure whether this correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's right. If the lives are independent, then the deaths are independent events (or boolean random variables), and you're essentially taking the exclusive-or.